# C++ : Is it possible to create a series of class objects (using a vector?) if the class disables the assignment operator?

Tags: c++, pointers, object, vector

I'm trying to create a set of planes within a mesh for each distinct value of x.
I have created a list of all my values of x, and the program/system I'm working with has a class for planes.

```
List<sampledPlane> planeListX;
vector normalX(1, 0, 0);
forAll(discreteX, x)
{
    sampledPlane xPlane
    (
        "xPlane",
        mesh,
        plane
        (
            point(discreteX[x], 0, 0),
            normalX
        ),
        word::null,
        true
    );
    planeListX.append(xPlane);
}
```

The code above is essentially a stupid number of typeDefs covering the declaration of a `vector<sampledPlane>` and then the operation `planeListX.push_back(xPlane)`. The constructor for my plane works nicely, and all compiles happily if the line `planeListX.append(xPlane);` is commented out (Although then obviously my vector remains empty).

When I uncomment the `append` line, I get a set of compiler errors with messages like:

```
/home/christian/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.2.2/src/sampling/lnInclude/sampledSurface.H:78:7: error: non-static reference member ‘const Foam::polyMesh& Foam::sampledSurface::mesh_’, can’t use default assignment operator
 class sampledSurface
```

I assume that the consequence of this is that I can't add constructed planes to a vector, because to do so requires copying the object.

Is it possible to in some way do this using pointers? Or should I dig through the libraries and attempt to rewrite the sampledPlane class to allow the use of the `operator=`? I'm pretty sure I will find that the operator is a `private` function with no implementation, designed only to block this sort of operation.

On a side note, is it better to write:
`planeListX.append(sampledPlane("xPlane",mesh,plane(...),word::null, true));` and avoid giving lots of planes the same name - my understanding is that these will be continuously overwritten in the case where they are named, and will be only temporary in both cases (either due to be temp, or to being scoped within the for loop anyway)

Comment: You could use pointers, that'd work fine. Before you do that though, try adding a move constructor, so that the object can be moved around without being copied. Also look into emplace_back. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be to use emplace_back. You pass in all the constructor arguments, instead of the constructed object. This allows the vector to create the object only once where it needs to.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do recommend that you don't disable the copy-assign (`operator=`) and here is why:

#### C++03

> There is no need to explicitly consider a user-defined operator& because elements must be copyconstructible (23.2 [container.requirements] para 3) and copyconstructible (17.6.3.1 [utility.arg.requirements]) specifies requirements for operator&.

#### C++11

Depends on the operation required, but in general it stayed the same.

So adding to your object copy construct ability will enrich the algorithms you may use from the `std`.

**Having said this**

To prevent this shortcomming, `C++11` defines `std::vector::emplace_back` which constructs your object in place, no copy or move operations are performed.

Those are your options.